# Mapping same feature class with map per data field (graduated symbols, customizable break values)?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages, map-book

I am trying to automate a mapping effort:  I am mapping a (FC) features class ( with multiple data fields representing different results). 
I need to visualize each data field  (from the same FC) using similar graduated color symbology (~ 5 classes) with specific brake values  for each data field. Save the layer, save the mxd, export a PDF.

How do I set up a Library for each data field (break values for symbology classes), iterating  through the data fields (field 1, field2, ….field36), updating layer symbology, save layer, save mxd, export PDF. I am using 3 data frames, each maps same FC with an definition query.

Comment: Do you have any experience with Python?

Comment: Obviously not enough. Learning.  I imagine arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer should do the trick. But I can’t figure out how to loop through the data fields. Perhaps create a Library first with the specific parameters for each data field??

Answer (score 3):

This script works on current mxd:

```
import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteoutput=True
try:
    def showPyMessage():
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
    def isLayerExist (mxd,lName):
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,lName)
        if len(layers)==0:
            raise NameError,'\n'+lName + " layer not found. Exiting.."+'\n'
        result=layers[0]
        return result
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    theLayer = isLayerExist(mxd,"Points")
    theFields=["aspect","arc2mdem"]
    theSplits=([-1,0,22.5,247.5,360],[0,10,20,30,70])
        sm=theLayer.symbology
        m=0
    for fld in theFields:
                breaks=theSplits[m]
                sm.valueField=fld
                sm.classBreakValues=breaks
                arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
                arcpy.RefreshTOC()
                m+=1
                arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, "D://rubbish//"+str(m)+".pdf")   
    del mxd
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

It works on 2 fields as an example, obviously you need to modify it to suit your needs. You might also consider adding

```
sm.classBreakLabels = ["0-10", "10-20" etc]
```